# What is the purpose of inheriting from enable_shared_from_this?

Tags: c++11

What is the point for a `class T` to inherit from `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>` ? I can't seem to figure out why you wouldn't just create a `std::shared_ptr<this>` ?

Comment: First of all, `this` isn't a type, you can't give it as a template argument to `shared_ptr`. Then the purpose is to allow safe creation of `shared_ptr` to `this` in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cppreference has a good example on why](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this).

If you want to return a `std::shared_ptr` of `this` while `*this` is already owned by a `std::shared_ptr` and you don't return `shared_from_this()` but return a new `std::shared_ptr<T>(this)` instead then you will end up with 2 shared pointers that don't know they're both owning the same object and thus the `use_count()` will be wrong which will cause a double `delete`, which is undefined behavior.